# Add a custom link/model to wagtail's admin sub-menu

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

Wagtail documentation explains how to:

- [Add an item to the admin menu](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#register-admin-menu-item)
- [Add a group/submenu to the admin menu](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/#a-more-complicated-example)

Let our model be `CustomManager` and its admin url be `/admin/custom_manager/`.

Using a hook, we can add a link to our page on to the first level of the admin menu:

```
@hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
def register_edit_menu_item():
  return MenuItem( 'Custom Manager', '/admin/custom_manager/', classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse', order=1000)
```

But how can we add this link to a sub-menu/group, when our model is not a wagtail model?

Comment: Is https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/admin_views.html#adding-a-group-of-menu-items what you're looking for?

Comment: @gasman thank you, this allows to add custom links to a sub-menu, but can I in this a sub-menu display a link to a model extending ModelAdmin alongside a link to a custom model?